# Is There A Universal Selector Option For if...in Clauses?

Tags: python

I have a "large" list of tuples:

```
thelist=[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]
```

I want to check whether any tuple in the list starts with a 1, and if it does, print "aaa":

```
for i in thelist:
    templist.append((i[0],i))
for i in templist:
    if i[0]==1:
        print("aaa")
        break
```

Which is rather ardurous as I have to create the templist. Is there any way I can do this:

```
if (1,_) in thelist:
    print("aaa")
```

Where _ is the universal selector. Note that the list would be very large and thus it is very costly to implement another list.

Comment: Such a universal selector does not exist. You will have find an alternative.

Comment: Why not just `for i in thelist: if i[0] == 1: ...`? What's the point of creating `templist` if you fill it with tuples just like `thelist`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't, although you can just use `any`

```
 any(i[0] == 1 for i in thelist) --> Returns true if the first element is 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t actually need the actual tuple, like you do in your example, then you can actually use tuple unpacking for exactly that purpose:

```
>>> the_list = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
>>> for x, y in the_list:
        if x == 1:
            print('aaa')
            break

aaa
```

If you add a `*` in front of the `y`, you can also unpack tuples of different sizes, collecting the remainder of the tuple:

```
>>> other_list = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
>>> for x, *y in other_list:
        if x == 1:
            print(y)
            break

[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Otherwise, if you just want to filter your list based on some premise and then do something on those filtered items, you can use `filter` with a custom function:

```
>>> def startsWithOne(x):
        return x[0] == 1
>>> thelist = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
>>> for x in filter(starts_with_one, the_list):
        print(x)

(1, 2)
(1, 3)
```

This is probably the most flexible way which also avoids creating a separate list in memory, as the elements are filtered lazily when you interate the list with your loop.

Finally, if you just want to figure out if *any* of your items starts with a `1`, like you do in your example code, then you could just do it like this:

```
>>> if any(filter(starts_with_one, the_list)):
        print('aaa')

aaa
```

But I assume that this was just an oversimplified example.